# am I allocating memory wrong?

Tags: c, malloc, allocation, calloc

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but some how Rtable[0,7] charges from 0 to 2 out of no where, i thought it was a allocation problem but I don't think i'm allocating it wrong, but th question is am i actually allocating memory wrong?

```
int *Rtable;
Rtable = (int *) malloc(sern * (2*sern) * sizeof(int));
initialize(sern, Rtable);

and my initialize method is:

void initialize(int sern, int *Rtable){
    int row, column;
    for(row = 0; row < sern; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < sern; column++){
            Rtable[row*sern + 2*column] = (row == column) ? 0 : 1000;
            Rtable[row*sern + (2*column) + 1] = (row == column) ?  row+1 : 0;
            printf("row: %d, and column: %d, data: %d\n",row, 2*column, Rtable[row*sern +2*column]);
            printf("row: %d, and column: %d, data: %d\n",row, 2*column+1, Rtable[row*sern +2*column+1]);
            //Rtable[row][2*column] = (row == column) ? 0 : 1000;
            //Rtable[row][(2*column)+1] = (row == column) ?  row+1 : 0;
        }
    }
    int i, k;
    for(i = 0; i < sern; i++){
        printf("data[%d] is : ", i);
        for(k = 0; k < (2*sern); k++)
            printf("%d:%d, ",k,Rtable[i*sern + k]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case sern = 4;

Comment: Allocation is right; calculation of array index is wrong. Tip: draw a picture of the matrix.

Comment: I drew the matrix and when through step by step, the results i get is the same as 
printf("row: %d, and column: %d, data: %d\n",row, 2*column,Rtable[row*sern +2*column]);
printf("row: %d, and column: %d, data: %d\n",row, 2*column+1,Rtable[row*sern +2*column+1]);
but the for(i = 0; i <sern; i++){loop} the value is different

Comment: Use a *struct* to stop shooting your leg off.

Comment: Allocation is wrong.  Don't use type casting on return value from **malloc(3)**.  Just `#include <stdlib.h>` (or `#include <malloc.h>` if you have an old compiler)  Type casting makes the compiler to assume you are right in the use you are making of **malloc(3)** and won't check for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns is actually `2*sern`. So the expression `Rtable[row*sern + 2*column]` should be `Rtable[row*(2*sern) + 2*column]`.

Comment: THANK YOU! that makes totally sense, i can't believe i didn't notice that.

Comment: @Mrjiang1992 you could make a macro like `#define R(r,c) Rtable[(r)*2*sern + (c)]` which will make the code a bit more readable

Comment: @HansPassant it looks OK to me. The table has `sern` rows and `2*sern` columns.